# Game using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to develop game similar to snake games in old model phones. I created the game, which you can have a look at [here](http://vignesh.hostingsiteforfree.com/snake.php). But when controlling the snake I switched the width and height of the snake to turn in any direction, but I want to make the snake to look like real snake, I mean it should have an L shape when turning and gradually changes into straight again, Please give me any idea, how I can do that using canvas. the snake is a fillrect() in canvas.

The following is the entire code..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Snake</title>
</head>
<body>
Use Arrow keys of to control the snake.
<canvas id="can_game" height="400" width="400" style="border:1px solid;"></canvas>
<div id="score_div"></div>
<div id="time">0.00</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var score=0,fps=30,canvas=document.getElementById("can_game"),context=canvas.getContext('2d'),dir="",score_div=document.getElementById("score_div"),width_h=45,pass='left',timediv=document.getElementById("time"),time=0.00;
var player = {
    color : '#ff00',
    px :'180',
    py : '384',
    height : '12',
    width : '45',
    draw : function(){
        context.fillRect(this.px,this.py,this.width,this.height);
    }
}
var ball = {
    x :Math.round(Math.random(4)*400),
    y : Math.round(Math.random(4)*400),
    draw : function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    context.arc(this.x,this.y,6,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    context.fill();
    }
}
setInterval(function(){
    score_div.innerHTML=score;
    timediv.innerHTML=Math.round(time/1000)+" Seconds";
    time=parseInt(time)+1000/fps;
    update();
    draw();
    var test=hitTestPoint(player.px,player.py,player.width,player.height,ball.x,ball.y);
    if(test===true)
    {
        ball.x=Math.round(Math.random(80)*400);
        ball.y=Math.round(Math.random(80)*400);
        score+=10;
        width_h+=3;
    }
    console.log(player.py,canvas.width);
    if(player.px <=0)
        player.px=360;
    else if(player.px >= (canvas.width))
        player.px=0;
    else if(player.py <= 0)
        player.py=360;
    else if(player.py >= (canvas.height))
        player.py=0;
    document.onkeydown = function() {
        var key_pressed = window.event.keyCode;
    /*  if(key_pressed == 32)
            dir = "freeze";*/
        if(key_pressed == 37)
            dir = "left";
        else if(key_pressed == 39)
            dir = "right";
        else if(key_pressed == 38)
            dir = "up";
        else if(key_pressed == 40)
            dir = "down";
};
},1000/fps);
function hitTestPoint(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2)
{
    if ((x1 <= x2 && x1+w1 >= x2) &&
        (y1 <= y2 && y1+h1 >= y2))
            return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function draw()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    player.draw();
    ball.draw();
    context.fill();
}
function update()
{
switch(dir){
    case "left":
        player.px-=3;
        player.width=width_h;
        player.height=12;
        break;
    case "right":
        player.px= parseInt(player.px)+3;
        player.width=width_h;
        player.height=12;
        break;
    case "up":
            player.py-=3;
            player.width=12;
            player.height=width_h;
        break;
    case "down":
            player.py+=3;
            player.width=12;
            player.height=width_h;
        break;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show some code to get help. It's very difficult to give an answer with the info you provided.

Comment: you're gonna have to use multiple rectangles

Comment: @SergioAristizábal: sorry dude, I'll correct that in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [CSS deck tutorial](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mqbdnpsl) to solve your problem.

Here the trick is , that the snake is composed of individual small and discrete blocks rather than the one as in your case where its a static block, and every time the snake is progressed one step, one block is popped from the rear and a new block is added to the top(face).

So when the snakes moves in another direction(or axis) its face block are gradually added in another  axis and it gives an illusion of snake turning in the way you expect it